# Log in twitter in android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j, jtwitter

I use the library "twitter4j" to interface with Twitter API. I need to write log in code but i don't understand very well how i can do it. I must write an application where user can specify username and password and i must take this value(username and password) and log in Twitter. I find a lot of kind documentation but I don't understand how I must use it. In details I don't understand why I must create an application with twitter account like this:

http://xmeng.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/how-to-handle-sign-in-with-twitter-using-twitter4j/

I need to log in with username and password but the example on the web log in with CONSUMER KEY and CONSUMER SEGRET KEY
can someone help me with some documentation?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to log in with username and password but the example on the web log in with CONSUMER KEY and CONSUMER SEGRET KEY

The Twitter API uses [OAuth authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth). This means you don't directly use the username/password, but instead use OAuth tokens returned to you after the user logs into Twitter. There is no documentation to show you how to just use the username/password because that's not how the Twitter API is intended to be used.